# Can detect the addEventListener and then remove it?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, event-listener

I wanna do this:

```
if (rightBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,goRight4))
{
rightBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,goRight4);
trace("YES")
}
else{trace("NO")}
```

above is the code i write to a Button.

I've added the eventListener but the result still trace NO.

Any idea or proper way to do this?

And what if the **rightBtn** have multiple event like MOUSE_OVER, MOUSE_OUT? can i remove them all with just 1 command?

```
rightBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,goRight4)
rightBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,goRightOver)
rightBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,goRightOut)

if (rightBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,goRight4))
{
rightBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,goRight4);
rightBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,goRightOver);
rightBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,goRightOut);
trace("YES")
}
else{
trace("NO")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is wrong. According to the AS3 language reference, `addEventListener()` returns void. You have to use `hasEventListener()` if you want to check if a listener was attached to your instance.

```
if (rightBtn.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK)) {
    rightBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goRight4);
    trace("YES");
} else {
    trace("NO");
}
```

But the best way to remove the event listeners is to remove it without knowing if it had been attached to your instance!

```
// Will not throw any error even if no listener was attached.
rightBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goRight4);
```

Comment: Right, calling `removeEventListener()` is harmless if the object isn't listening for the event in the first place. And as stated in @puggsoy's answer, you can sometimes be fooled by using `hasEventListener()` because that method will return true if some other class has added an event listener. I up voted both answers :)

Answer (score 4):

You can check if an object has an event listener added to it with `hasEventListener()`, like this:

```
if(rightBtn.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK))
{
    rightBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goRight4);
    trace("YES");
}
else
{
    trace("NO");
}
```

You'll notice the the `hasEventListener` function only has one parameter, the event. This is OK in most cases though, since you probably won't have multiple listener functions for one event.